# Add a row at the end of SQL Select using UNION

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a view in a record using some filters and i have to add lines that contains just ids from another table and a specific row at the end of the sql result.

So the expected result is something like that:

```
    Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column4
1   0001     | 565      | AM1      | DR01
.
.
59  TEST1    |          |          |
60  NON_IMMO |          |          |
```

Line 59 is the id from the second table and line 60 is the specifix row.
My query is like that :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.asset_id 
 , a.serial_id 
 , a.VIN 
 , b.project_id 
  FROM ps_asset a 
 WHERE --Some conditions  
  UNION 
 SELECT PO_GROUP_ID 
 ,' ' 
 , ' ' 
 , ' ' 
  FROM PS_PO_GROUP_TBL 
  UNION 
 SELECT 'NON_IMMO' 
 ,' ' 
 ,' ' 
 ,' ' 
  FROM dual
```

But the problem is using this I don't get the specific row at the end.

I feel like the SGBD show the 2 UNIONS ordered by alphabet.

```
    Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column4
1   0001     | 565      | AM1      | DR01
.
.
59  NON_IMMO |          |          |
60  TEST1    |          |          |
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change the last `UNION` to a `UNION ALL` to skip elimination of duplicates (which as a side effect orders the lines). That should be enough...

```
...
FROM PS_PO_GROUP_TBL 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'NON_IMMO' 
...
```

Comment: Yes you're right for the this specific row i am sure i will not have any duplicate line, that's why `UNION ALL` do the job.

Answer (score 2):

A UNION isn't going to force an order on the records.  You'll need another false 5th column to ensure the data goes to the end.  See example

```
SELECT COLUMN1
FROM
(
SELECT COLUMN1, 0 ORDER_BY FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT 'FOOTER' COLUMN1, 1 ORDER_BY FROM DUAL
)
ORDER BY ORDER_BY
```

Also, if you data possibly matching what's at the end, you'll want to use UNION ALL instead to ensure the record still gets added.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will become:

You must wrap your query in one main query where you can apply a global ORDER BY

The second: I've removed DISTINCT because UNION remove the duplicate

```
SELECT asset_id, serial_id, vin, project_id
FROM
(SELECT a.asset_id, a.serial_id,
    a.VIN, b.project_id 
FROM ps_asset a 
WHERE --Some conditions  
UNION 
SELECT PO_GROUP_ID, ' ', ' ', ' ' 
FROM PS_PO_GROUP_TBL 
UNION 
SELECT 'NON_IMMO', ' ', ' ', ' '  
FROM dual)
ORDER BY serial_id
```